# Viewfinder and focal length in film medium format

Tags: film, viewfinder, medium-format, hasselblad

I just got a Hasselblad 500cm. I'm used to the rangefinder system where framelines indicate the frame corresponding to a certain focal length.

In my Hasselblad there is no such a thing. So I'm wondering, how do you adjust the angle of view depending on the lens you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hasselblad 500C/M is a single lens "reflex" camera. That means that the image you see in the viewfinder is a through-the-lens view reflected to the viewscreen by a mirror. When you adjust the angle of view by changing the lens focal length, this change is translated to the viewfinder because what is projected into the viewscreen is coming through the same lens that is going to be used to expose the film.

Everything you see in the viewfinder should also be in the image captured if you are shooting at the full 6x6 cm format.

If you don't have one already, you can download a PDF of the full [500C/M manual](http://www.cameramanuals.org/hasselblad/hasselblad_500c_m-swc_m.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

There is no separate viewfinder. It's an SLR. You are looking through the lens.